# Authentification error - ASP.NET web API and Angular 7 on IIS server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, angular7, saml, iis-10

In my web application hosted on **IIS server** (**.Net web API** & **Angular 7**), I am using **SAML authentification** and I have a problem when I try to log in the website for the first time, it shows me the error bellow:

[image]

If I press Ctrl+F5 or I referesh it works perfectly.

PS: I added all configurations needed of headers in my *web.config* like this :

```
    <customHeaders>
            <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS" />
   </customHeaders>
```

PS2: In my local environement I don't have this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help/advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to configuring iis CORS module according to the content in this link:

https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module.

If it still does not work, then open your IIS manager and select the website -> Bindings, change the port to your custom port, for example: 8090.

Comment: Hi @samwu, the first solution dosen't work for me, and the second one I can't try it (I have "https" so the default port is 443 can't change it).

Comment: Then you can try to see if there are related error messages in the Event viewer.